# (Java) Regex exclusion Sonar rule

Tags: regex, sonarqube

I need to create a sonar rule with regex.
I have :

```
j++] 
j++   ]
j++)
j++   ) 
j++,
j++  ,
for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
```

I want all except the last with a regex rule.
I use `\+\+\s*(,|]|\))\s*` and i get all.
I use `\+\+\s*(,|]|\))\s*(!\{)` and i get nothing.

How can I get what I want to ?

Comment: Check [`\+\+\s*[\][),]`](https://regex101.com/r/fR3iE2/1)

Comment: Perhaps, [`\B[+]{2}\s*[],)]\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/zR5wP7/1)? What is the programming language/platform?

Comment: Java, i have to detect any '++' in an instruction like list[i++];

Comment: If your intent with `(!\{)` is to find a character which is not an opening brace, the regex syntax for that is `[^{]`.  If you want either that or end of string, `($|[^{])`.

Comment: Then, are you looking for the [`[+]{2}\s*[\],)]\s*(?!\s*[{])`](https://regex101.com/r/zR5wP7/2)? Note that in Java, backslashes must be doubled. It will find the pluses with punctuation, except those in front of `whitespace`+`{`.

Comment: Thanks all ! stribizhev's solution works !

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[+]{2}\s*[\],)]\s*(?!\s*[{])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR5wP7/2)

Note that in Java, backslashes must be doubled.

It will find the pluses with punctuation, except those in front of <kbd>**whitespace(s)**</kbd>+<kbd>**{**</kbd>.

[Java code sample](http://ideone.com/KfPkMX):

```
String s = "++]\n++ ]\n++)\n++ )\n++,\n++ ,\nfor (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+]{2}\\s*[\\],)]\\s*(?!\\s*[{])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```